# Scroll to the last position on back

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to scroll a page to the last scrollbar position when the users go back in the history. I've searched in the forum and i wrote a function for my page and looked a lot of examples but it wont work...

When the user click on a link, i save the scrollbar position before going forward and then, when the user go back it should scroll to the last position

This is the code:

```
  window.onscroll = function() {
  var scrollPosition = window.scrollY;
  localStorage.setItem("scrollPosition", scrollPosition);
}

window.onunload = function() {
  var storage = localStorage.getItem("scrollPosition");
  console.log(storage);
  if(storage && storage != 0) {
     window.scroll(0, storage);
  }
}
```

can You guys tell me where i'm wrong?

Comment: window.onload, not onunload but I suggest you debounce the storing

Comment: _This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers_